# Activity without onStart and onStop + Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-activity

I have a problem. All my activities are without methods **onStart** and **onStop**. All the code is inside **onCreate**. All activities are ended with **finish();**

But I want to integrate Google analytics inside my project.
The instructions are following:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
      EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

     EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
  }
```

Shall I just create these methods and leave them empty? Or I can put EasyTracker methods inside **onCreate** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this methods code like you posted in your question.

The thing is: All Activities have `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods, you are just *overriding* them to add some additional code (here the analytics tracker) when the Activity changes its state.

Take a look at this activiy life-cycle diagram here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

---

[image]